# Flexslider is not working in IE

Tags: flexslider, woothemes

I am trying to implement the basic flexslider on our website. It works well with chrome, Firefox and safari. But in all versions of IE, it just blows out the entire width and height of the page. [Here is the link](http://www.yummicandles.com/Affiliates_10001_10001). Please advise

Comment: You might want to take a look at something like [this article](http://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-flexslider-and-ie-89-investigating-a-possible-bug/) that can be found from [Google searching](https://www.google.com/)...

Answer (score 1):

I tried this one it work for me.

Add following line in the header tags to force IE to render in the latest document mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem in ie9 - solved by setting fixed width for div, containing slider in CSS.

```
.metaslider { width: 720px; }
```

Hope this helps.