# Jquery slideshow display differently in IE 11 than in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code below displays a jquery slideshow of three pictures that, when clicked, each transform into videos. When I try to view the page in Internet Explorer version 11.165, the left and right arrows in the slideshow are missing when you hover over the picture. And, when a video begins playing and you try to move to the next slide, the video overflows to the left or the right. This overflow happens only in IE and for the video slides, not for the picture slides. In Chrome, I don't have this problem. How do I make those arrows visible in IE 11? And how do I prevent the overflow that shows me 2 or 3 slides simultaneously?

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        start: function(slider) {
            $('body').removeClass('loading');
        },
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#Alexandra_Saunders_image").click(function() {
        $("#Alexandra_Saunders_slide").html('<video poster="https://static.gbtimes.com/uploads/old/2017/07/02/launch-longmarch5-wenchang-july2-2017-full-cns-2_cropped.png" controls preload="none">' +
            '<source  src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">' +
            '</video>');
    });

    $("#Anthony_Salvatore_image").click(function() {
        $("#Anthony_Salvatore_slide").html('<video poster="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/24701-nature-natural-beauty.jpg/1280px-24701-nature-natural-beauty.jpg" controls preload="none">' +
            '<source src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">' +
            '</video>');
    });

    $("#Ashley_Valencia_image").click(function() {
        $("#Ashley_Valencia_slide").html('<video poster="https://cdn.allwallpaper.in/wallpapers/1280x720/12708/nature-beach-palm-trees-palms-tropics-1280x720-wallpaper.jpg" controls preload="none">' +
            '<source src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">' +
            '</video>');
    });
});
```

```css
 @font-face {
     font-family:"flexslider-icon";
     src: url("https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/SiteAssets/flexslider-icon.eot") 
    /* EOT file for IE */
}
 @font-face {
     font-family:"flexslider-icon";
     src: url("https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/SiteAssets/flexslider-icon.ttf") 
    /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}
 a:hover {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
 #WoodenBackgroundContainer{
     width: 100%;
     height: 1300px;
}
 #container{
     margin: 0 auto;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     width: 1000px;
     height: 1300px;
     background: linear-gradient(#88D4E6, #0C4E78) !important;
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#0C4E78);
    /* For IE 11*/
     text-align: center;
     position: absolute;
}
 .flexslider{
    height: 416px;
     max-width: 746px;
     background-color: #696969;
     margin: auto;
     margin-top: 4px;
}
 .flexslider img{
    height: 416px !important;
}
 .flexslider video{
    height: 416px !important;
     width: 100%;
     object-fit: inherit
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.wellframe.com/js/flexslider/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script defer src="https://www.wellframe.com/js/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="WoodenBackgroundContainer">

    <div id="container">

        <div style="overflow: hidden; height: 480px;">
            <div class="flexslider">

                <ul class="slides">

                    <li id="Alexandra_Saunders_slide">
                        <img id="Alexandra_Saunders_image" src="https://static.gbtimes.com/uploads/old/2017/07/02/launch-longmarch5-wenchang-july2-2017-full-cns-2_cropped.png">
                    </li>

                    <li id="Anthony_Salvatore_slide">
                        <img id="Anthony_Salvatore_image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/24701-nature-natural-beauty.jpg/1280px-24701-nature-natural-beauty.jpg">
                    </li>

                    <li id="Ashley_Valencia_slide">
                        <img id="Ashley_Valencia_image" src="https://cdn.allwallpaper.in/wallpapers/1280x720/12708/nature-beach-palm-trees-palms-tropics-1280x720-wallpaper.jpg">
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: take a look at this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021627/flexslider-is-not-working-in-ie

Comment: @MhdAlaaAlhaj I tried setting the fixed width and putting the meta tag in the head, and neither worked. <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />. Any other ideas that I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will get straight to your questions with my answer:

**How do I make those arrows visible in IE 11?**

The problem here is with your font-face css. I've changed the css so that it makes the arrows work in IE and other browsers.

**how do I prevent the overflow that shows me 2 or 3 slides simultaneously?**

Set overflow to hidden on the `.flexslider`. This causes the pager to become hidden but you can play around with related styling to make the pager visible again.

**Modified CSS:**

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "flexslider-icon";
   src: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/fonts/flexslider-icon.eot');
   /* IE9 Compat Modes */
   src: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/fonts/flexslider-icon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
   url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/fonts/flexslider-icon.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
   url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/fonts/flexslider-icon.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
   url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/fonts/flexslider-icon.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
   /* Legacy iOS */
 }

 a:hover {
   text-decoration: none !important;
 }

 #WoodenBackgroundContainer {
   width: 100%;
   height: 1300px;
 }

 #container {
   margin: 0 auto;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 1300px;
   background: linear-gradient(#88D4E6, #0C4E78) !important;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#0C4E78);
   /* For IE 11*/
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
 }

 .flexslider {
   height: 450px;
   max-width: 746px;
   background-color: #696969;
   margin: auto;
   margin-top: 4px;

   /* set overflow to hidden to fix IE11 overflow visible bug */
   overflow: hidden;
 }

 .flexslider img {
   height: 416px !important;
 }

 .flexslider video {
   height: 416px !important;
   width: 100%;
   object-fit: inherit
 }

/* make the pager visible when overflow is hidden on the .flexslider */
.flex-control-nav{
  bottom: 0;
}
```

I've created a codepen as jsfiddle doesn't play well with IE11: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyGNzQ

Comment: you are a genius, thank you so much, that worked! I set it so that the hidden overflow portion is only activated in IE10 and higher, and I left out the pager visibility style so that the user can only see the pager in non-IE browsers.

(at-symbol)media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
 .flexslider{overflow: hidden !important;}
}

Comment: You're welcome! I personally would prefer to stay away from hacks when all possible but then again, this applies to an image slider - which in most cases, isn't content that would be prioritized. Plus, you're using `-ms` prefixes, so they don't affect modern browsers - nice! 

Also, you may want to mark the question as answered if it worked for you.